# Tidy returns empty string

Tags: php, tidy

On my local server, this works fine. However, when I try to do this on the production server, the following returns an empty string:

```
$tidy = new tidy();
$tidy->repairString($html);
```

`$html` has actual HTML content before repairing (I checked), but `repairString` returns an empty string. Does this indicate a configuration error? Is libtidy not properly installed? How can I go about debugging this particular issue?

**EDIT:** See comments. I've found a very simple way to remove the Tidy dependency, so this question no longer needs an urgent answer. Even so, I'll leave it up for reference.

Comment: Does your production and local server have the same PHP version?

Comment: @Anthony Forloney: Production is 5.2.12, local 5.2.10 (but Ubuntu hasn't pushed out 5.2.12 to the repositories yet).

Comment: Ah, I know Ubuntu like I know Mars, so that sounds like jibberish to me. Can you do a `var_dump` of `$html` before you throw it into `repairString`?

Comment: I did; there's content. I'll not bother pasting the entire downloaded HTML file for you :)

Comment: I'm starting to think I typed something wrong compiling PHP long, long ago, and that it can't find libtidy. That doesn't sound like a fun problem to solve.

Comment: Yeah, I do not blame you, try to do a clean re-install on the production server, not sure if its a buggy install but it doesn't hurt to try.

Comment: I have never used tidy, but is there a reference to `localhost`? or `127.0.0.1` anything that would relate to working on your local server opposed to production?

Comment: ...I've just noticed that all I'm using tidy for in this case (I wrote this code a while back) is so that I can parse the HTML to find onclick attributes that match a certain regex. By just running the regex on the full HTML, I get the desired results without doing any HTML parsing. Wish I noticed that a while ago. Tidy dependency removed; problem solved by nature of having found a much easier solution. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Its likely that you have different error reporting settings for a production server.  Check your error log to see if it reports a failure here.

Comment: Not a problem, im glad its solved.

Comment: You should write your solution as an "answer" and accept it so that this question doesn't appear under "No answers".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I don't actually really need Tidy, so I removed the dependency. That was a sufficient answer for me.

Even so, this question remains up for reference.